# Control output size of modelsummary or DT in bookdown

Tags: r, markdown, dt, modelsummary

How can I control total size or width of elements like `datasummary_skim` from `modelsummary` package or `datatable` from `DT` package in `bookdown`? Those packages are great. But output is too large. I can zoom in and out via browser view, which looks perfectly fine. The commands themselves don't come with these options. Perhaps there is a general html feature to control the size of a code chunk output?

````
---
title: "Output Size"
author: "Author"
date: "Today"
output: html_document
---

Test 

```{r cars}
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars)

library(modelsummary)
datasummary_skim(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modelsummary` does not actually draw tables itself, but instead support 4 table-drawing packages: `kableExtra`, `gt`, `huxtable`, `flextable`. Each of these packages offers functions to customize the output, and most include options to customize the size of (at least some) elements.

For example, in the default `kableExtra` output:

```
library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)
datasummary_skim(mtcars) |>
    kable_styling(font_size = 8, full_width = FALSE)
```

Please refer to the documentation of these packages for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For a **DT** table, you can use the `width` option:

```r
datatable(mtcars, width = "60%")
```